# How to loop over a nested array in handlebars 1.3 with ember (that works on iOS8)

Tags: ember.js, ios8

I found an issue that only seems to be a problem on iOS8 and I wanted to see what a work around would be.

```
var SessionsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    everything: function() {
        var models = [{time: "x", sessions: []}];
        return models;
    }.property()
});
```

In the above controller I create a models array and push new objects into it... yet on iOS8 I get the following error (in the middle of the run loop it seems) when I use the nested template below

> TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.

This is the template

```
<table class="table table-border">
  <tbody>
  {{#each group in everything}}
    <tr>
    {{#each session in group.sessions}}
      <td>yo</td>
    {{/each}}
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

here is my bower.json to show all the versions I'm using

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.1",
    "ember-resolver": "0.1.7",
    "handlebars": "1.3.0",
    "ember": "1.7.0",
    "ember-loader": "*",
    "fauxjax": "0.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.2.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an iOS 8 Safari bug.

After some debugging I have a first pass at a ghetto work-around https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/5629

As far as i can tell this does not affect  iPhone 5s or Retina Mini's but it does affect 4s 5 and 5c

There also appear to be other very similar issues when subclasses Native object like DOM elements. The symptoms may be similar, but they seem to happen regardless of the device. I suspect they may be related but we may have a special snow flake.